# how to clear data attribute from input using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do I clear the `userid` attribute of a specific input field? Even when I clear the field the `userid` is not cleared, because I am fetching the data on the basis of the ID in input field of the textbox, it also fetches the data of the `userid` which is not present in the textbox because it gets stored and is removed only after refresh(f5).

```
<input id="inputField_0" 
       type="text" 
       class="inputClass ui-autocomplete-input" 
       autocomplete="off" 
       userid="10018" />
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java

Comment: `userid` is not a valid html attribute... not that you can't use it, but if you want to store arbitrary data with an element I'd suggest using `data-userid`.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage jQuery's [`removeAttr`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method.

```
$("#inputField_0").removeAttr("userid");
```

Or if you need a vanilla JS option, you can leverage the element's [`removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) method.

```
document.getElementById("inputField_0").removeAttribute("userid");
```

Comment: Since the OP does not mention JQuery, I suggest you provide a pure JavaScript solution. Although JQuery is popular, it is not used by everyone.

Comment: Please don't use w3schools :) MDN is much better!

Comment: You're correct :) but MDN offers much higher quality information. It's the de facto source for JavaScript documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove userid attribute from input field using JQuery.

```
Try the below link.
Visit [https://jsfiddle.net/gmk9zotq/3/]
```